# VBA Redim Preserve

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I dont know how to populate a multidimensional array. Here is my code i just started to understand but i dont know what is wrong, it is not working except for one loop.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Arr1 As Variant
    Dim Row As Long
    For Row = 0 To 3            
        ReDim Arr1(9, Row)
        Arr1(0, Row) = "Zero"
        Arr1(1, Row) = "One"
        Arr1(2, Row) = "Two"
        Arr1(3, Row) = "Three"
        Arr1(4, Row) = "Four"
        Arr1(5, Row) = "Five"
        Arr1(6, Row) = "Six"
        Arr1(7, Row) = "Seven"
        Arr1(8, Row) = "Eight"
        Arr1(9, Row) = "Nine"    
        Row = Row + 1
        ReDim Preserve Arr1(9, Row)        
    Next Row
    MsgBox Arr1(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: the first redim is inside the for???

Comment: Are these going to be hard-coded values that you are placing into the array (i.e. is the code in the question just a MCVE, or is that actually the data you want to use)?  Or are you going to set the values from a range in a worksheet?  Or are they calculated values?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim limit As Integer
    limit = 3 'get limit from somewhere

    Dim Arr1 as Variant        
    Redim Arr1(0 To 9, 0 To limit) As Variant

    Dim Row As Long
    For Row = 0 To 3            
        Arr1(0, Row) = "Zero"
        Arr1(1, Row) = "One"
        Arr1(2, Row) = "Two"
        Arr1(3, Row) = "Three"
        Arr1(4, Row) = "Four"
        Arr1(5, Row) = "Five"
        Arr1(6, Row) = "Six"
        Arr1(7, Row) = "Seven"
        Arr1(8, Row) = "Eight"
        Arr1(9, Row) = "Nine"        
    Next Row
    MsgBox Arr1(0, 0)
End Sub
```

You already know the limits you want your array have so just define the limits at the start. You don't need to redefine these at any further point.

Also, `Next Row` does the same thing as `Row=Row+1` so you don't want both

**Update**

If you like you can also put your strings in an array

```
Sub test()
    Dim limit As Integer
    limit = 3 'get limit from somewhere

    Dim Arr1 as Variant        
    Redim Arr1(0 To 9, 0 To limit) As Variant

    Dim numbers As Variant
    numbers = Array("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine")

    Dim Row As Integer, Col As Integer
    For Row = 0 To 3
        For Col = 0 To 9
            Arr1(Col, Row) = numbers(Col)
        Next Col
    Next Row
    MsgBox Arr1(0, 0)
End Sub
```

**Update 2**

*There really are so many ways to skin a cat...* How about using collections:

```
Sub test()
    Dim numbers As Variant
    numbers = Array("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine")

    Dim col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 3 'get limit from somewhere
        col.Add numbers
    Next i

    MsgBox col(1)(0)  'col(1 to 4)(0 to 9)
End Sub
```

Comment: in fact row +1 will make the iteration 2 step shorter

Comment: Thanks - I didn't explain that well!

Comment: Hi thanks, but the second dimension 0 to 3 is not fixed and it is dynamic how can i change it?

Comment: No problem, I updated the code. Get the limit at the beginning of the code and that will update the size of array

Answer (score 2):

Range can be used to repeat them without a loop:

```
Dim r As Range, Arr1
Set r = Cells.Resize(10, 4)

r = [{"Zero";"One";"Two";"Three";"Four";"Five";"Six";"Seven";"Eight";"Nine"}]     
Arr1 = r           ' Arr1 is now (1 To 10, 1 To 4) As Variant
r.ClearContents
```

Comment: Wizardry!.. Nice answer

Comment: Wizardry? Hardly. Beautifully elegant - yes :)